# Rodando programa em segundo plano

Tags: java

Como rodar um programa em segundo plano, e quando o usuário pressionar uma tecla o programa faça algo?

Eu só sei fazer com o programa em foco.

Comment: se entendi corretamente, você quer que sua aplicação fique monitorando as teclas que são pressionadas, independente dela estar com foco ou não. Fazer isso não é algo tão trivial, você poderia tentar usar a biblioteca [jnativehook](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/wiki/examples), se caso for isso mesmo que você está procurando eu posso colocar como resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47369/rodando-programa-em-segundo-plano/48757#comment97206_47369), você pode utilizar a biblioteca [JNativeHook](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/), segue código de demonstração que está na própria página da biblioteca.

```
import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;

public class GlobalKeyListenerExample implements NativeKeyListener {
    public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));

        if (e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
            GlobalScreen.unregisterNativeHook();
        }
    }

    public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key Released: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
    }

    public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key Typed: " + e.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
        }
        catch (NativeHookException ex) {
            System.err.println("There was a problem registering the native hook.");
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());

            System.exit(1);
        }

        //Construct the example object and initialze native hook.
        GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeKeyListener(new GlobalKeyListenerExample());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que você queira rodar parte do seu programa em outra Thread.

Dê uma olhada na classe Thread.

No método disparado pelo clique do botão, você executar a tarefa em outra Thread enquanto a Thread principal continua.

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Seu código aqui
    }

}.start();
```